# Randomly display dots

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

I am trying to design a little game using JS, and what I want it to do is make a random number say... 1-100 and then randomly scatter the dots (I used periods with the font size at 200) on the screen. By random, I just mean that I don't want them to be arranged in rows and columns. What I have so far achieves all but scattering the dots, so how do I do that?

```js
var i = 0;
var inhtml = "."
var num = 10

function exe() {
  i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  //alert(i)
  while (i <= 100) {
    document.getElementById("dot").innerHTML = inhtml + "."
    inhtml = document.getElementById("dot").innerHTML
    if (inhtml.length > num) {
      inhtml = document.getElementById("dot").innerHTML + "<br />"
      num = num + 20
    }
    i++;
  }
}

exe();
```

```html
<div id="dot"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a single element containing several periods at a large size, I'd recommend using separate elements for each dot. Then, (besides not having to use 200px periods), you can use CSS to position each element however you want. I have an example [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Cs4hK/):

```js
function createDot(x, y) {
  var elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.setAttribute("class", "dot");
  elem.setAttribute("style", "left:" + x + "px;top:" + y + "px;");
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(elem);
  return elem;
}

function anotherDot() {
  createDot(Math.floor(Math.random() * 200), Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  anotherDot();
}
```

```css
.dot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
}
```

**Edit:** I don't know what the exact problem with getting the dots to not overlap you're having is, but you basically need to do this:

First you pick a position. Then, you check that position against all the other positions (which you'd probably want to do using [Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance)). If the point is valid, you use that point and add it to the array of taken positions. Otherwise, go back to the first step.

Comment: Wow, that looks just about perfect!! Is there any way to make them not overlap though? or maybe change the color of each dot or something? I need some way to make it possible for the user to count the dots.

Comment: @Sean: Well, if you store all the positions it's picked in an array, whenever it's picking a new position, it could check if it's too close to any other position, and if so, pick a different one. You could also pick a different color by setting a different `background` property for each element.

Comment: I would rather that it simply checks to be sure they are not too close.. not sure how I'd do this though.

Comment: I think I'll pass... it shouldn't come up enough for it to be worth the trouble.. Thanks anyways for trying!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the HTML 5 Canvas. It allows you draw arcs (aka circles) In any postion, size, and fill color.

Look [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#divingin) for details, [here](http://s831.us/gPpsMp) for a tutorial, and [here](http://s831.us/fgbm4J) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your syntax errors before progressing; I do not know whether you copied all of your code, but you are missing semicolons at the end of your lines. Syntactical issues aside, one possible way to achieve what you describe would be to assign the x- and y-coordinate of each point to a random number. Examination of the code reveals that only the initial value of `i` is assigned to the value of `random()`. Incrementing `i` will make the coordinates of future points dependent on the initial value of `i`, which is something you may want to take into account. But nowhere in your code do I see you changing the position of the each element based on the values you generate.

I strongly suggest that you use the HTML5 Canvas instead of attempting to move HTML elements; the latter would be cumbersome and lead to messy and inefficient code. If you still want to stick to the method you are trying to use now, check to make sure that the CSS `display` property is set to `block` for these elements. You are using the `getElementById()` method, which is not very useful in this circumstance, since IDs are unique in HTML files. I would suggest using `getElementsByTagName()` and using those returned elements with a specific `class` attribute instead.

Comment: JavaScript does not require semicolons at the end of lines.

Answer (score -1):

To not be bound by the browser's text layout constraints, you pretty much have to absolutely position your dots:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: {random number}; left: {random number}">.</div>
```

Comment: Would there be any possible way to be sure the dots don't overlap by too far?

Comment: @Sean Keep track of the generated positions in an array and compare each time you generate new coordinates. That won't be random anymore though, and true randomness should be pretty randomly distributed already. The worst that should happen is two overlapping dots, but they should rarely if ever, for example, all crowd in one corner.

Comment: I would need some way for the user to be able to count the dots. At a number as high as 100, it would be quite a task, but if the number was only, say 10, how could I ensure that there are 10 visible dots, and not 9?